# Temporarily store chats and pictures in chat application

Tags: php

I am using **HTML, CSS, JS, PHP** and **MySQL** to develop a chat application close to messenger apps like WhatsApp or Signal. I have encountered two problems while making the application. The problems are listed below. Please help with them:

i) When the user uploads a profile picture, I want it to be stored just in the database (temporarily) and not in any permanent directory to maintain the privacy of the user. I cannot figure out how will I achieve this.

ii) I dont want the chats to be stored in the database. However, I have planned of a temporary table which would store the chat message till the time it gets delivered and once the message would be delivered, it would be deleted from the table but stay on the user's chat page.

Please help me if anybody knows any solution with these two problems.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume, since it appears you have not tried anything yet, that you are just hoping for **concepts** to help you move forward.

You state you want information to be stored in a database temporarily. In one scenario this is an image, and in another scenario this is text.

**Store an image in a database**

Without asking about your implementation, I can assume you want to do this ([you might not](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-advisable-to-save-an-image-as-a-BLOB-in-MySQL)). You would store this as a BLOB or maybe even better as a LONGBLOG type. You can get the image data for insertion by using the built in [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function in PHP.

It's probably a good idea to limit the size of images that can be uploaded. [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) could be helpful here.

If you want to make this temporary, you can do several things, one thing could be storing a timestamp in a column next to the image called `expires` or something similar and simply running a cronjob every so often to delete rows that have exceeded the expired time, or deleting them at whatever interval you feel is right.

**Store text in a database, delete it, but still let the user see it**

This is more murky, you want your cake and you want to eat it as well. If me and you had a conversation in your application 3 days ago, how can I see the messages you sent me if they are gone from the database? This is outside the realm of PHP because you would now need to save these conversations locally on each device, the keyword "cache" comes to mind.

Maybe when each message is sent you are caching all the messages on every users device who is part of a specific conversation. If that would be the case you would not even really need a database, and might well do better with a sockets implementation.

I hope this helps you get started. You have no code to review and help with and it looks like you might not have tried anything yet. Please come back when those 2 things have changed :-)

Comment: I liked your idea of implementing sockets. I would surely try them and get back in touch with you